# how to insert multiple value from single textbox to different rows in the Database?

Tags: insert, bulkinsert

I have two values in a single textbox such as 1,2 ... Now i want to insert this two values into the oracle DB in different rows i.e in same column but in different rows. how can i perform this one?

Comment: have you tried anything?